# Different results when encrypting with OpenSSL

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I have a strange case when I try to do encryption with OpenSSL

Details:

- I try to encrypt file with "Hello World!"
- Password (String): "testtesttesttest"
- Password (HEX): 74657374746573747465737474657374

Terminal commands to encrypt file:

- For plain text password

  - `openssl aes-128-cbc -e -a -nosalt -iv [some vector] -k [password] -in [input file] -out [output file]`
  - `openssl aes-128-cbc -e -a -nosalt -iv [some vector] -pass pass:[password] -in [input file] -out [output file]`
- For password in HEX format

  - `openssl aes-128-cbc -e -a -nosalt -iv [some vector] -K [HEX password] -in [input file] -out [output file]`

So the only difference in commands is that one uses plain text password while another uses the same password but in HEX form. So in my opinion the result of encryption should be the same. But the Base64 output is actually different.

Maybe somebody know and can hint what could be the case here?

Another case that now I develop a small application that encrypts files on Blackberry phone and I would that it would be compatible with other encryption software like OpenSSL that are available on PC. So the Base64 output of my application is not the same as OpenSSL produces with the given password.

The sample code looks like this:

```
String testKey = "testtesttesttest"; (example)

byte[] aesKeyAsBytes = testKey.getBytes();

AESKey aesKey = new AESKey(aesKeyAsBytes);

AESEncryptorEngine engine = new AESEncryptorEngine(aesKey);

CBCEncryptorEngine cengine=new CBCEncryptorEngine(engine, new InitializationVector(_initVector));

PKCS5FormatterEngine fengine = new PKCS5FormatterEngine(cengine);

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

BlockEncryptor cryptoStream = new BlockEncryptor(fengine, outputStream);

cryptoStream.write(plainText, 0, numOfPlainTextBytes);

cryptoStream.close();

byte[] cipherText = outputStream.toByteArray();

outputStream.close();

return cipherText;
```

Comment: I don't know much about OpenSSL, but using a password probably applies some sort of KDF and uses the result as the key.  Whereas the hex-encoded string is likely directly used as the key since it's exactly 128 bits.  I imagine if you passed a hex string with one extra byte (e.g. `00`) on the end, you'd likely get an error?

Comment: @luke-park. If it's true so this means that OpenSSL AES encryption is not compatible with other tools that implement AES-128-CBC and others algorithms. Plain text password contains 16 chars so it should be precise 128 bit key.

Comment: Well, that's not what it means.  It means that if you want to use that string directly as the key (which is a bad idea), then you need to hex encode it first.

Comment: @luke-park. I'm a little bit confused. For example I encrypts photos and choose password "Honeymoon_In_Hawaii". So it means that files encrypted by OpenSSL cannot be decrypted by other tools and vice versa. The case that I need to remember HEX form of "Honeymoon_In_Hawaii" also look not good enough.

Comment: @luke-park. The whole thing is actually that I now develop a small program for my Blackberry on JDE 7.1.0 that encrypts files with AES. But I cannot decrypt them afterwards with OpenSSL on PC since plain text password is processed differently by Blackberry SDK and OpenSSL.

Comment: @LargoWinch: If you added that part (about interoperability with your Java code) into the question, that would make it (marginally) on-topic here on Stack Overflow. As it stands, though, your question is purely about using the OpenSSL command line tools, and thus properly belongs on [SU].

Comment: @ilmari-karonen: I have added a sample code from my app to the topic. But also maybe this question will be more suitable for such places as [security.stackexchange.com] or others. Maybe somebody else has such misunderstanding on how plain text passwords that we using becomes secret keys actually used for encryption. Thanks to luke-park now I understand what actually the problem is in my program. That I need to replace aesKeyAsBytes = testKey.getBytes() with some KDF used by OpenSSL or other software in order to make it compatible vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following inputs as test data for this scenario:

```
Key (Hex): 01010101010101010101010101010101
IV  (Hex): 02020202020202020202020202020202
Plaintext: Hello, World!
```

Using the above inputs with the following command in OpenSSL:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -K 01010101010101010101010101010101 -iv 02020202020202020202020202020202 -e -a -in in.txt -out out-openssl.txt
```

Gave me a result of:

```
wT6aF/PXrGhxEwyX6mNfXA==
```

---

Using the C# `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace, which has a raw AES implementation that we can test against, I used the following code:

```
using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
{
    aes.KeySize = 128;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    aes.Key = new byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    aes.IV = new byte[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };

    byte[] plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
    ICryptoTransform t = aes.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] ciphertext = t.TransformFinalBlock(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length);

    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertext));
}
```

To produce the exact same base64 result of:

```
wT6aF/PXrGhxEwyX6mNfXA==
```

---

This demonstrates that the OpenSSL command above is the correct one to use if you wish for the key to be used exactly as provided (e.g. the `-K` flag with the uppercase K).

As I mentioned in comments, OpenSSL **does** use a KDF when providing a password as plaintext, as detailed in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/36981/what-are-kdf-parameters-in-openssl-command-line-utility-for-enc).

Comment: Thanks for the link. That was usefull reading. Otherwise when using keys in HEX there is no problem with Blackberry SDK neither. So I think I need just accept that it is not possible to use plain text with OpenSSL in conjunction with other tools and I need to find another software. GPG also out of scope. Hmm...

Comment: I think it is probably worth understanding **why** you can't use a key made of simple latin characters.  Using a phrase as an actual encryption key is a **very unintelligent** thing to do.

Comment: This is fully possibly. Maybe I'm using Blackberry SDK encryption classes not correctly. But this I can look into and improve. But in my mind if one software implements AES-128-CBC for example and another software implements the same algorithm so they should be compatible vice versa.

Comment: The algorithms are completely compatible.  The key derivation is just different.  The `-k` argument causes the input to be fed through a KDF first to produce a key.  The `-K` argument uses the provided hex directly as the key.  The actual AES part is exactly the same, the keys are just different.

Answer (score 1):

From man page for enc which should be present on any Unixy system (sometimes under a modified section like 1ssl) [or current release on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/enc.html):

```
-k password

    the password to derive the key from. This is for compatibility with 
    previous versions of OpenSSL. Superseded by the -pass argument.

-kfile filename

    read the password to derive the key from the first line of 
    filename. This is for compatibility with previous versions of 
    OpenSSL. Superseded by the -pass argument.

-K key

    the actual key to use: this must be represented as a string 
    comprised only of hex digits. If only the key is specified, the IV ...
```

Do you see any difference between '(the) password the key is derived from' and 'the actual key'?

PS: since `-K` does not do key derivation, the arguments related to salt `-nosalt -salt -S` have no effect on it and are ignored.

Comment: Yee. Actually I should have looked into man. I have checked -help option that says:

  ` -k val         Passphrase -pass val      Passphrase source`